# Design Advise Needed for Lookup Roll Up Summary Without a Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, roll-up-summary

I have a custom object called Sales Leaders which contains a field called total AGP (Allocated Gross Profit). This needs to be the sum of all Sales Leader AGP values on the Opportunity. It's not possible to create a roll up summary between the two objects directly, so I have been trying to come up with a workaround.

What makes this tricky is that there are two Sales Leaders for each Opportunity. SL1 and SL2 are two lookup fields, and two currency fields SL1 AGP and SL2 AGP.

Is there any other way to roll up the data from those fields to the Sales Leader object without writing a trigger? I'm trying to use the built in functionality if possible, even if slightly clunky.

So far I have looked at creating a child object and using flows & processes to move the data but neither offer a perfect solution, mainly as a result of having 2 Sales Leaders for each Opportunity. 
I have also tried the declarative roll up summary tool by AndyInTheCloud which although works, was too slow for our needs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more on the data model.  
I mean how the opportunity and custom object related to each other.... by lookup or master detail relationship

Comment: At present, there is no relationship between the two objects. Ideally, I would have created a master detail between the Sales Leader (master) object and Opportunity (detail) and then roll the values up from the Opportunity. However since the Opportunity cant be on the detail side I will have to use a Lookup.